# How to set the date and time programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, cocoa-touch

I have a requirement in which we need to programmatically set the date and time (or sync the time) from a server.

How is it done in iOS?

Is there any Apple documentation which says we cannot do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set the date and/or time on iPhone/iPad programmatically. Those APIs are considered protected by Apple. In other words if you were to use those APIs and submit an app using them it would be rejected.

**Edit**:

To get documentation on this you can contact Apple Developer Technical Support using one of your free tech support incidents included with your developer program. [LINK](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#techSupport)

Comment: Any clue how to do it with private API?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments to your posters are saying, you can't, because although there is an API to do that, it is "private" and can only be used by Apple. Thus, if you do this, Apple will reject your app because the use of private APIs is verboten on the App Store.

There is no alternative solution. You'll have to explain to your client that as a third party developer, you cannot change system settings, end of story.

Comment: Do you know how to do it with private API?