# Set Android and iPhone datetime

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Do you know how to set an Android or iPhone device's datetime
 using a feaure within your mobile app 
that you built using Delphi XE5?
This should of course happen at runtime.

Comment: Programmers seem to want to control everything. You think that you program is in charge of time?!

Comment: Are making a joke there David? I laughed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi offers no cross-platform way of setting the system time.

[On iOS, you don't have access to the API for changing the time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15572403/33732); that functionality is reserved for the OS.

[On Android, you need elevated privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11708781/33732), and then you can use [`AlarmManager.setTime`.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setTime%28long%29) At that point, your problem is simply one of adapting the native Java techniques to Delphi. I assume that's pretty much the same for any API, so it's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the insight and advice