# How to programmatically set iOS device time?

Tags: ios, datetime

Is it possible to remotely set iOS device date and time programmatically?

And How?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, Apple does not permit an app (other than ones they've written) to muck with settings on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not possible.** You can only do it manually in the `Settings` app of your `iDevice` or switch it to be set automatically.

Answer (score 1):

you can`t .
please read this:

[iOS - How to set the date and time programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572339/ios-how-to-set-the-date-and-time-programatically)

You can't set the date and/or time on iPhone/iPad programmatically. Those APIs are considered protected by Apple. In other words if you were to use those APIs and submit an app using them it would be rejected.

if you don`t care to be rejected ,try this:

[Changing iPhone's date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278450/changing-iphones-date-and-time)