# Is it possible to change iOS device Hour Time programmatically

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Is it possible to change iOS devices **Hour Time** programmatically from third party applications?

I can change the iOS Device `Hour Time by Settings->General->Date & Time`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with the public API. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107315/how-to-programmatically-set-ios-device-time) answer for reference.