# Check if datetime setting is automatic in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, settings

I am very new to iOS development and I am aware that this is a duplicate question. However 3 years have passed since last time it was asked, so I was wondering if anything has changed regarding iOS api? Thanks in advance

Duplicate question: [Check if the device datesettings is automatic in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529627/check-if-the-device-datesettings-is-automatic-in-ios)

Comment: Why don't you try by yourself and find out? let us know too the result.

Comment: I would if I could. Google isn't being very helpful.

Comment: Try the answer you mentioned in link dear

Comment: @Dev_Tandel So I take it as a confirmation that nothing has changed in last 3 years regarding datetime API?